# Sort by type while retaining numerical ordering in Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, sorting, windows-2000

Windows XP and later OSes have a [NoStrCmpLogical API](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319827/the-sort-order-for-files-and-folders-whose-names-contain-numerals-is-d) that allows sorting numerically rather than lexicographical.

All references say this is not supported until *after* Windows 2000, yet, somehow that does not seem to be the case:

[image]

On the ***left***, you can see **lexiographic** (string) sorting, which Microsoft alleges is the behavior in Windows 2000 and prior.

On the ***right***, you can see **numerical** sorting, which is the default starting with Windows XP (although lexicographic is still possible).

Clearly, both of the sorting algorithms work, depending on how Explorer is sorting.

It seems:

- When I sort by **Type**, I observe lexicographic sorting, *which Microsoft claims is the only sorting behavior in Windows 2000*
- When I sort by **Name**, I observe numerical sorting, *which, according to Microsoft, should not even be possible in Windows 2000*

I prefer sorting by **Type**, because the file extension of a file tends to be more important to me than its actual name, so it's easier to find things that way, particularly in folders with lots of files.

However, I also prefer *numerical* sorting. Windows 2000 seems to bundle numerical sorting with sorting by name. I set the default to Type, but this seems to enforce lexicographic sorting.

Can I have my cake and eat it, too? Is there a way to sort by Type while retaining numerical sorting?

Comment: Two things come to mind. _Grouping_ by type and sorting by name (right-clciking on Group header > Collapse all is great for folders with lots of files) is one. The other option is sort by `Type` and then `<Shift>+<Click Name Column Haeader>` should set the secondary sort to `by Name`.

Comment: @KeithMiller Neither pressing SHIFT nor CTRL+SHIFT beforehand seems to accomplish anything different, unfortunately. It just sorts purely by name then. I know I've used this trick elsewhere (Excel?) but it doesn't seem to work in Explorer.